# How can I get my site to look the same when it is restored down?

Tags: html, css

My site looks fine when the page is maximized but poor when restored down how do I fix this?  Basically the box on my site gets distorted when I restore down.  I am new to website design.  My coding is below:

```
.boxed {
        position: absolute;
        left: 500px;
        right: 180px;
        border: 4px solid green;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center; 
        }
```

suggestions?

Comment: What does "minimized" mean here? It typically means the site isn't shown at all because the browser is just an icon.

Comment: Try starting with googling for Responsive Design. What does this mean, How to start etc...

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) **No**. Please read the [help] to see what questions you can [ask] about

Comment: Bad question, bad design,so, bad result...

Comment: The Responsive Design is what I am looking for thank you and I am sorry about posting the site I realize I should have just showed the code my apologies I will delete the post.

Comment: To Clarify the site looks fine in browsers when the page is completely maximized, however if you minimize the page my box text stretches out. The coding I have is as follows:

Comment: .boxed {
position: absolute;
left: 500px;
right: 180px;
border: 4px solid green;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center; 
}

Comment: I said minimize and I meant restore down your right bad question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Box**
The box covers the image, and make the image blocked by border. You can consider to fix the width and height using `px` or something like that, just make sure that it doesn't `overflow`s the place it should be.

e.g. Add this to your boxes' style

```
width: 500px;
height: auto; /*For the height auto will be okay*/
white-space: pre-wrap /*Line-break*/
display:inline-block;
```

And this, will probably improve your website.

Comment: Always its better for floating websites to be in % not px and it depends how you want it to be

Comment: Yes, also good enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
.boxed {
            position: relative;
            left: 10%;
            right: 180px;
            border: 4px solid green;
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            width:48%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

Replace this with yours

Comment: Thank you Syed for your answer